# Get children of React.Fragment

Tags: reactjs

I'm returning `React.Fragment` in my component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MyFirstElement/>
      <MySecondElement/>
    </Fragment>
```

Now I want to process all children in the parent component.
I can get the Fragment component itself via `this.props.children`.

**My Question**

But how can I get the children of the `Fragment` component so that I can also process the children of `Fragment`?

Comment: `this.props.children` are the children that were *passed* to this component, not the ones *it returns*.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've changed my question. I hope now it makes more sense.

Comment: Please elaborate the question. "*I'm returning Fragment*"; You're rendering it right? Where are you expecting the 'return'? Please show us a [mre].

Comment: @MatthiasM Thanks for the clarification! The question is much clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to 'edit' the children passed to a component, the best option is to create a custom component in which you have full control over the children.

Since the component only returns its children, it behaves like a `Fragment`

Small example to demonstrate this"

1. `<Parent />` returns a `<CustomFragment>` with 2 `<Child />` components
2. The `<Child />` component expects a `testProp` value, but `<Parent />` does not provide it
3. In our `<CustomFragment>` we `map()` through our children, to add the `testProp` expected by `<Child />`

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <CustomFragment>
              <Child />
              <Child />
            </CustomFragment>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return <p>{`Deep #${this.props.testProp}`}</p>
    }
}

class CustomFragment extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        
        // Render children
        return this.props.children.map((child) => {
        
            // Change child if needed
            // For example, lets add a testProp
            child.props['testProp'] =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
            
            // Return
            return child;
        });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's helps. The point, I've missed is, that I do not have to use Fragment but create my own Fragment Component.

Comment: Just a suggestion, React recommends using [`React.Children.map()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) (or other `React.Children` utilities) with `children` since `children` is an opaque data structure.